# Read different lines from file to work with

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

So, I have file like this:

```
Mark Brown
12 2345
45 6780


63 3210
Peter Tailor

10 15430
114 1230
23 3450



John Smith
234 12130
11 32410
```

The name is obvious, below the name there is X lines with the ID and a VALUE in each line (there are blank lines too). I need to write out to a file every name, and the biggest VALUE's ID, like this:

```
Mark Brown 45
Peter Tailor 10
John Smith 11
```

If there was only one name, I could do it simply, but with X names in it, I have no clue :(
Any ideas or help?

Comment: Can't you just execute the code that will handle only one name in a loop? That said, your file format is not great for this, ideally you should use one that lets you tell when a "section" begins and ends using some sort of delimiter.

Comment: Assuming your IDs are always numbers and the letters never start with numbers, just loop through the lines and for each number create a dictionary key, initialised like `mydict[key] = 0` and then for every subsequent line for the same `key` do something like `mydict[key] = max(value, mydict[key])'

Comment: Anyway, unless your input file is insanely large, I'd consider first *parsing* it into some sort of datastructure. (A list of `Person` objects, of which each contains a list of `(id, value)` tuples that correspond to the lines found under a name.) Then working with the datastructure should be fairly straightforward - loop over the `Persons`, and for each one use [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=max#max) with the `key` parameter to get the ID with the greatest value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got some spare time, so here is the code to create your dictionary. I'll let you as an exercise to understand each line :)

```
from itertools import groupby
with open('testing.txt') as file:
    goodlines = [line.strip() for line in file if line.strip()]
    splitted = list( list(val[1]) for val in groupby(goodlines, lambda l: l[0].isdigit()))
    names = [ list(val)[0] for val in splitted[::2] ]
    val_split = [ [v.split() for v in val] for val in splitted[1::2] ]
    val_sorted = [ sorted(val, key=lambda v:int(v[1]))[-1][0] for val in val_split]
    result = dict(zip(names, val_sorted))
print result
```

Comment: Thank you EnricoGiampieri, that helped so much. I just started python (this is my first python program as a first year softw. engineer) I tried to do it all by myself with google, I am at ~30 lines now, but didn't finished yet. I try to edit your code to meet the requirements I did already in my code. Thank you so much.

Comment: The important thing is that you try to learn from the answers, and not just sinply reusing them. you know, receiving a fish versus learning to fish :)

Answer (score 0):

I think first you read every line and check if it beginns with a letter or a number (aka if ist's a name or an ID)* and then you create an element for each name with a list that contains all the IDs. You sort them using a sorting algorithm and after that, you simply write out everything (that should be no problem)

*You also have to check for empty lines

Comment: "sort them using bubblesort" - **really?!**

Comment: (Seriously, Python already comes with a built-in sorting algorithm in [`list.sort()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list.sort#list.sort) and [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) that's basically a work of genius, why would you bubblesort. AFAIK bubblesort is the one that's taught as a counterexample to good algorithm design.)

Comment: I'm not familar to phyton so I didn't know that. That was only an example, but if you want, you can use something else for sorting as well.

Comment: It was a pretty terrible suggestion for any programming language. Even in the absence of a built-in sort (in, I dunno, assembly), you should not use bubblesort.